# C# Async Await on a Prism message

Tags: c#, callback, async-await, messaging

Is it possible to await on a callback from a Event Aggregator such as prism?

```
    MessageManager.Subscribe("Reply", this.GetType().Name, Myfunc);

    private void Myfunc(object obj)
    {

    }

    public async void MyFunc2()
    {
        MessageManager.Publish("Request", xxx);

        await [Message Reply]
    }
```

There is the ugly method of Subscribe followed by a unsubscribe in a lambda but this is not very pretty.

Is there a better way to do that?

EDIT:

This is the solution I have so far:

```
    private SemaphoreSlim dataReady = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    MeasurementDataSet lastDataSet;

    public Calibrator(IMessageManager msgMgr)
    {
        MessageManager = msgMgr;

        MessageManager.Subscribe("NewMeasurementData", this.GetType().Name, OnMeasurementData);
    }

    private void OnMeasurementData(object obj)
    {
        lastDataSet = (MeasurementDataSet) obj;
        dataReady.Release();
    }

    public async void Calibrate(IParameterCache prmCache, Action<string> updateText)
    {

        MessageManager.Publish("InitiateMeasurement", "CAL ");
        await dataReady.WaitAsync();

        // do stuff             

        MessageManager.Publish("InitiateMeasurement", "CAL ");
        await dataReady.WaitAsync();
        // do stuff  
        MessageManager.Publish("InitiateMeasurement", "CAL ");
        await dataReady.WaitAsync();
        // do stuff  

    }
```

Comment: Prism is hardly a _"message bus"_

Comment: Event Aggregator

Comment: What do you mean by `await [Message Reply]`? Is it awaiting something happening in `MyFunc`?

Comment: `async-await` might not be the best option here. It never is for event streams.

Comment: The thing is that it controls a hardware machine on the background and has to go through a specific process, so using await async is much easier than having callbacks everywhere. @PauloMorgado

Comment: Beware that `async-await` does not handle a stream of events. It's one shot only. Rx, on the other hand, is for streams of events.

Comment: I'm not handling stream of event @PauloMorgado, I send a command and wait a feedback. Since the app is modularly designed, the different modules communicate through an event aggregator. I updated the question for the solution I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) to await an event

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<Request>>().Subscribe( payload =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 ); // only fake work
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<Response>>().Publish( new Response() );
        }, ThreadOption.BackgroundThread );
    }

    private async void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        ( (Button)sender ).IsEnabled = false;
        try
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>();

            using ( var token = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<Response>>().Subscribe( payload =>
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult( payload );
            }, ThreadOption.BackgroundThread ) )
            {
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<Request>>().Publish( new Request() );
                await tcs.Task;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ( (Button)sender ).IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}

public class Request
{

}

public class Response
{

}
```